# Read lines from file and split line on last delimiter in Python and save it to another file

Tags: python, string, split, delimiter

I have a file named data.txt which contains names, mails and addresses separated by a colon. It looks like this:

```
first_name1:last_name1:mail1@mail.com:address1
first_name2:last_name2:mail2@mail.com:address2
first_name3:last_name3:mail3@mail.com:address3
first_name4:last_name5:mail4@mail.com:address4
first_name5:last_name6:mail5@mail.com:address5
first_name6:last_name7:mail6@mail.com:address6
first_name7:last_name8:mail7@mail.com:address7
```

I would like to read only addresses and store it in separate file called addresses.txt (one address in a line). I tried such a code:

```
#name of file to store addresses
file_save = open("adresses.txt", 'a')

with open('data.txt', 'r') as file_to_open:
    data = file_to_open.read().rsplit(":",1)

    file_save.write(data[-1])

    print(data) #for testing only

file_to_open.close()
```

BUT it gives me such a result:

```
['first_name1:last_name1:mail1:address1\nfirst_name2:last_name2:mail2:address2\nfirst_name3:last_name3:mail3:address3\nfirst_name4:last_name5:mail4:address4\nfirst_name5:last_name6:mail5:address5\nfirst_name6:last_name7:mail6:address6\nfirst_name7:last_name8:mail7', 'address7']
```

What i have done wrong?

I try to make it something like this:

```
address1
address2
address3
...
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the `split` method on each line of `data`

```
file_save = open("adresses.txt", 'a')

with open('data.txt', 'r') as file_to_open:
    data = file_to_open.readlines();
    for address in data:
        file_save.write(address.split(":")[-1])

file_to_open.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `csv` and a comprehension:

```
import csv 
with open('data.txt') as rf, open('address.txt', 'w') as wf:
    wf.writelines(a[-1] + '\n' for a in csv.reader(rf, delimiter=':'))
```

Or without `csv`:

```
with open('data.txt') as rf, open('address.txt', 'w') as wf:
    wf.writelines(a.split(':')[-1] for a in rf)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = file_to_open.readlines()

for line in data:
    print(line.split(':')[-1])
```

Comment: you should at least provide some explanation, why it's different with the other answers

Answer (score 0):

```
file_save = open("adresses.txt", 'a')

with open('data.txt', 'r') as file_to_open:
    data = file_to_open.read().split("\n")  # first split into lines
    addresses = []  # initialize address list
    for line in data:
        address = line.split(":")[-1]  # get last element splitted by ":"
        addresses.append(address)  # save to addresses
    file_save.write("\n".join(addresses))  # one new line between each entry

file_save.close()  # this needs to be file_save not file_to_open
```

Answer (score 0):

i can help you.

My `datas.txt` file:

```
first_name1:last_name1:mail1@mail.com:address1
first_name2:last_name2:mail2@mail.com:address2
first_name3:last_name3:mail3@mail.com:address3
first_name4:last_name5:mail4@mail.com:address4
first_name5:last_name6:mail5@mail.com:address5
first_name6:last_name7:mail6@mail.com:address6
first_name7:last_name8:mail7@mail.com:address7
```

My code:

```
# My datas file
filename = 'datas.txt'

# A function for parse the lines
def get_lines():
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    return lines

def parse_and_extract():
    lines = get_lines()
    # First, we should open the result file.
    with open('result.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:

        # Parse the lines and get the addresses
        for line in lines:
            # Get the address
            address = line.split(':')[-1]

            # Finally write the address to result file
            file.write(address)

parse_and_extract()
```

Finally, my `result.txt` file:

```
address1
address2
address3
address4
address5
address6
address7
```

I hope i could help you.